# Adding an input tag with js and dom appendChild seems to have no margin

Tags: javascript, html

When I add input tags with DOM `appendChild()` in a js script they seem to have no margin as they have no separation in between them. Input tags that have been written in the html file have that separation. The element inspector says they all have the same style.

[image]

The js script:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
```

I don't know how to google this problem so I ask here, what's going on and how can I fix this in the js script?

Comment: That is likely due to missing whitespace in the generated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a whitespace or give a class with margins

```js
// without
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));

// with whitespace

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));

// with css
const input = document.createElement("input");
input.classList.add("spaced")
document.body.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(input.cloneNode(1));
```

```css
.spaced { margin-right:5px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the margin as follows:

```js
let inp = document.createElement("input");
inp.style.margin='4px';
document.body.appendChild(inp);
inp = document.createElement("input");
inp.style.margin='4px';
document.body.appendChild(inp);
```

Comment: Works wonders, but I'd prefer not to mess with the style when it's just a whitespace that's missing in the html

Answer (score 0):

The space between the input is not a margin, it's propably a white a space, so when you add an element with js it's appended without spaces, if you wrap the two inputs with a div with the style `font-size: 0` you will see this space dissapear even for the inputs added in html